# C# How to connect to Azure Cosmos DB without connectionstring/primary keys?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to use the Azure Cosmos DB and I would like to implement it without using connectionstring or primary key. I set up a system assigned Managed Identity and I would like to have an outcome like the Azure Blob Storage connection. Meaning, you can connect to the Azure Blob Storage by just implementing it into the Dependency Injection and using only the URI for that (and of course the container name).

Is that possible or I can just save the connectionstring into Azure Key Vault and get it from there?

I can try initiating the cosmos client with connectionstring in the Key Vault, but I would rather just use URI (and database, container names) to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create the credential to use a managed identity:

```cs
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
```

Then, register the cosmos client as a singleton:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(new CosmosClient("endpoint", credential));
```

Resources:

- [Access Cosmos DB Data using managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-vm-managed-identities-cosmos?tabs=azure-portal#access-data)
- [Create CosmosClient with default credential implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/how-to-dotnet-get-started?tabs=azure-cli%2Cwindows#create-cosmosclient-with-default-credential-implementation)